# Linked List Inserting in sorted format

Tags: java, linked-list

```
package practise;
public class Node 
{
    public int data;
    public Node next;

    public Node (int data, Node next)
    {
        this.data = data;
        this.next = next;
    }

    public  int size (Node list)
    {
        int count = 0;
        while(list != null){
            list = list.next;
            count++;
        }
        return count;
    }

    public static Node insert(Node head, int value) 
    { 
        Node T;
        if (head == null || head.data <= value) 
        {
            T = new Node(value,head);
            return T;
        } 
        else  
        {
            head.next = insert(head.next, value);
            return head;
        }
    }

}
```

This work fine for all data values less than the first or the head. anything greater than than doesn't get added to the list. So for example in my main method Node root = new Node(200,null) any node I create now on greater than 200 doesn't get added.please explain in simple terms thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with your code is that it depends how the insert is called. I don't know how you are calling insert in your code. Below code would work fine, with list sorted in descending order:

```
public class SortedLinkedList {
public static void main(String[] a) {
    Node head = Node.insert(null, 123);
    head = Node.insert(head, 13);
    head = Node.insert(head, 3123);
    head = Node.insert(head, 3);
    head = Node.insert(head, 87);
    head = Node.insert(head, 56);
    head = Node.insert(head, 2332);
    head = Node.insert(head, 5187);
    do {
        System.out.print(head.data + ", ");
        head = head.next;
    } while (head != null);
   }
}

class Node {
public int data;
public Node next;

public Node(int data, Node next) {
    this.data = data;
    this.next = next;
}

public int size(Node list) {
    int count = 0;
    while (list != null) {
        list = list.next;
        count++;
    }
    return count;
}

public static Node insert(Node head, int value) {
    Node T;
    if (head == null || head.data <= value) {
        T = new Node(value, head);
        return T;
    } else {
        head.next = insert(head.next, value);
        return head;
    }
}

}
```

Comment: Hey thanks it solved it The problem was they way I was calling it in my main method, I was doiing Node head = new Node(200,null); then I  kept doing this head.insert(); it should have been like this head = head.insert(); BUT can you please explain what is the difference in that two statements please thanks again. (Like in the if I know im returning The T which is the head but in else Im returning head not head.next Im confused over there how dow does that make sense):D

Comment: Your method insert() always returns the reference to head node of the list. U just need to keep track of it by assigning the return value  every time. BTW this is not a good way to program. Try it in a way that your calling code just passes the values to the linked list object....

Answer (score 0):

You don't want to insert if head.data is less than value, you want to insert if value is less than head.data.

Answer (score 0):

`if (head == null || head.data <= value)`
Your problem is here, when you insert 200 to the head. Anything greater than 200 will not be added. Because you did `head.data <= value`.You add 200 to the head, then head is not `NULL` anymore, so then your program will check if `head.data <= value`, if yes, add it to the list. Otherwise don't.

```
public static Node insert(Node head, int value) 
        { 
            Node T;
            if (head == null || head.data >= value) 
            {
                T = new Node(value,head);
                return T;
            } 
            else  
            {
                head.next = insert(head.next, value);
                return head;
            }
        }
```